# Double integral over a specific region

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I was given an exercise:

Calculate the integral of $\begin{gather*}
    \iint_D (\sqrt{x/a}+\sqrt{y/b})^2 \,dx\,dy
\end{gather*}$, where D is the region bounded by the curve $\sqrt{x/a}+\sqrt{y/b}=1$ and two axes. $a$ and $b$ are both positive real numbers.

I tried to draw the region of D but doesn't find it useful to compute directly or use polar/spherical coordinates, but I feel like there's some connection between the region and the function inside the integral.Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $u=\sqrt{\frac{x}{a}}$ and $v=\sqrt{\frac{y}{b}}$. Then $\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}=4abuv$ and the transformation $(x,y)\mapsto\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{a}},\sqrt{\frac{y}{b}}\right)$ maps $D$ bijectively to the triangular shaped region  beneath the curve $v=1-u$ in the first quadrant of the $uv-$plane. We get $$\iint_{D}\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{a}}+\sqrt{\frac{y}{b}}\right)^2\mathrm{d}A=\int_0^1\int_0^{1-u}4abuv(u+v)^2\mathrm{d}v\mathrm{d}u=\frac{ab}{9}$$

Comment: thanks for your solution！Is it often the case when the region has some connection with the function inside the integral then we use change of variables？

Comment: Yes, you see that happening among many problems which involve a change of variable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried these coordinates?
$x=a r \cos^4 (t)$, $y=b r\cos^4 (t)$, $r \in [0,1]$, $t \in [0,2\pi]$.